# Using Visual Format Language with Scroll View that has dynamic number of views

Tags: ios, swift3, autolayout, scrollview, visual-format-language

I am converting a `UIScrollView` course that has a Scroll View with a static number of view to a dynamic number of views.  The static views are constrained using Visual Format Language as below:

```
page1 = createAndAddTutorialStep("bg_1", iconImageName: "icon_1")
    let page2 = createAndAddTutorialStep("bg_2", iconImageName: "icon_2")
    let page3 = createAndAddTutorialStep("bg_3", iconImageName: "icon_3")
    let page4 = createAndAddTutorialStep("bg_4", iconImageName: "icon_4")
    let page5 = createAndAddTutorialStep("bg_5", iconImageName: "icon_5")
    pages = [page1, page2, page3, page4, page5]

    let views: [String: UIView] = ["view": view, "page1": page1.view, "page2": page2.view, "page3": page3.view, "page4": page4.view, "page5": page5.view]
    let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[page1(==view)]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
    let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[page1(==view)][page2(==view)][page3(==view)][page4(==view)][page5(==view)]|", options: [.alignAllTop, .alignAllBottom], metrics: nil, views: views)
```

My question is, if you have a Scroll View and the number of views are only known at runtime, must you always use Visual Format Language? Is Autolayout an option?  The views are UIImages. I won't know the number until they are downloaded.

Comment: First, No, you don't need to use VFL ... Next, VFL is a way of describing constraints for Autolayout, so you use VFL ***with*** Autolayout, so the 2nd part of your question makes no sense. What are you really trying to do? You say the views are UIImages, but you name them "page" ... maybe a UIScrollView is not your best option... Try describing what you want to do.

Comment: I will be using this Scroll View in many areas throughout my project.  In this case, I have images with embedded text that presents the history of the customer.  So paging makes sense.  I'll also use this Scroll View to present to users an introduction to the app.  I'll be using it to present many other things that make more sense than using Collection Views.

Comment: OK, well... it sounds like using a `UIPageViewController` might make more sense. But, if not, then a scroll view with paging enabled can also be a good option. So, you can use VFL (or other methods) to set the constraints. And, depending on what all you need to do, using a `UIStackView` inside the scroll view, and then adding your "pages" as `.arrangedSubviews` may be an easier way to manage it.

Comment: Forgive me, but you say "you can use VFL (or other methods) to set the constraints".  I got that.  Can I use Autolayout?  How?  I can't pin to a view that doesn't exist in Interface Builder?

Comment: Terminology confusion... I think when you say "Autolayout" you mean "Visual layout in Interface Builder"? This is **VFL**: `...withVisualFormat: "V:|[page1(==view)]|"...` and this is **another method**: `v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)`. Each is a way of setting constraints (via code) that are ***used by*** the Autolayout engine.

Comment: Dynamic number of cells are usually handled with table view or collection views. `UITableView` is vertical direction only whereas `UICollectionView` can be both vertical and horizontal, in case you haven't used them before...

Comment: I have Zhang.  I need a Scroll View that presents dynamic number of subviews.  Thanks.  I'll use Visual Layout Format.  I'll just build the constraints dynamically I guess.

Comment: @MartinMuldoon - Are your "pages" the full size of the ScrollView? If so, I strongly recommend either `UIPageViewController` or putting them in a `UIStackView` inside the scroll view. Either way pretty much eliminates the "build the constraints" work.

Comment: How can I put them in UIStackView when they are added to the subview at run time? Each of the  "pages" is meant to be the size of the subview.

Comment: Briefly... Add a Stack View to your Scroll View... "pin" the stack view to all 4 sides... set width and height constraints, but give them priority of 999... at run time, set width & height constraints on each "pageView".... then use `stackView.addArrangedSubview(pageView)` for each "page" you want to add... boom - you're done.

Comment: @MartinMuldoon - thinking about your task, and the way you describe *"pages meant to be the size of the subview"*, I really think `UIPageViewController` could be your best bet. If you haven't worked with it yet, give it a look.

Comment: Hey DonMag, sorry for not responding.  I thought about your suggestions and they seem to make sense.  I won't be able to give it ago till tomorrow.  I'll certainly let you know.  Thanks!

Comment: DonMag.  I was successful adding a Stack View to the Scroll View.  It worked like a charm.  Thanks!  For some reason I can't integrated this with my main project.  Keeps crashing (nil while unwrapping an optional).  Reconnected all outlets, and made sure Story Board Identifier is correct.  I've set breakpoints everywhere.  All of the code seems to execute.  Just crashes on the Main Thread.  Thanks again.